# Pinging domain names resolves but times out

Tags: networking, ip

Computer's IP address goes "Bad". No internet access. Local network still works fine. Can ping any other computer on the network. I can ping the DNS server. Pinging external domains resolve but time out. Nslookup responds correctly. Other computers on the network have internet access. If I change a computer's MAC address to the same MAC address as the computer with the "bad" ip address (and turn that computer off), it pulls the same IP address and experiences the same problem. We are using DeepNines web filter. What could be possibly causing this intermittent problem?

Comment: Might be a wrong route/gateway, at least that is in my experience a common but often overseen error.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like two pieces of equipment on the same switch with the same MAC address.  This happened to me several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like somewhere along the line something firewall-like is blocking the IP.

One thing you can do to determine where it breaks down is to run a traceroute (on windows, `tracert`), and then ping each server in the path; this may get you closer to where the problem lies.

It's also possible that a misconfigured NAT device is doing something odd to the traffic, or that you have a subnetting issue (this will happen if the subnet mask on the gateway is incorrect and it thinks the host isn't in its subnet, sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my problem:

(which seems to be OP's problem from what I'm reading)

```
tracert www.cisco.com

Tracing route to e2867.dsca.akamaiedge.net [2600:1406:40:584::b33]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *     ^C
```

or

```
 ping www.ripe.net

 Pinging www.ripe.net.cdn.cloudflare.net [2606:4700::6812:142c] with 32 bytes of data:
 Request timed out.

 Ping statistics for 2606:4700::6812:142c:
 Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
 Control-C
 ^C
```

It's worth mentioning that I found an answer to this problem on my network by disabling ipv6 on my network adapter. I determined that not only was my bandwidth improved by doing so, but also realized, due to process of elimination, that my ipv6 wasn't completely configured.

I had a Google DNS plugged in for ipv4, but not for ipv6. Once I plugged in the Google DNS for ipv6 my problem went away.

I know this is almost 9 years too late, and I'm not entirely sure if ipv6 was even rolling out at the time of this post, but I felt it worth mentioning.